# Google Developer Console API limits?

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I'm working with a potentially large number of Android applications and I need to know what my limitations are in the Google developer console for organizational purposes. Specifically, I'd like to know if there is a daily limit for creating new projects, an account limit for total projects, a daily limit for keys per project (or even per key type or per account), or an account limit for total API keys.

For reference, I plan to use a single Android application key (for maps and such) and a single Server application key (for GCM) per Android app I publish. This is mostly for the sake of determining whether I should maintain all of my keys in a single project, or keep a pair of keys per project and potentially have dozens to hundreds (or even thousands) of API projects. I would prefer having individual API projects for each, but I am concerned about possible per-account maximums.

Comment: Google generally has a limit for everything. I'm not aware of them publishing what the limit of developer applications is though.

Comment: I was unable to find any published limit. The Google representative to whom I spoke suggested I ask other developers (apparently in hopes that someone has encountered such limits and therefore knows).